# Return values from nested lists into PandasDataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have a list containing 2 lists that looks as the follows:

```
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

What I need to have at the end of the day, is to have 2 columns in a PandasDataFrame, the first column should hold the values found in the first list, and the second column should hold the values in the second list.

I want to iterate over each of these lists and return every single value in it into a separate column in PandasDataFrame. Where col0 in PandasDataFrame should hold the values in the first list, and the col1 in PandasDataFrame should hold values in the second list.

I am expecting output like this:

[image]

Is there a compact way to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: Can u add some sample input & expected ouput to get a precise solution

Comment: Can you please check the modifications @Sushanth

Comment: did you try `pd.DataFrame(yourList).T` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this is by converting the list into a dictionary and then creating a Data Frame from that dictionary as explained below:

```
l =[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]

# Creating a dictionary using dictionary comprehension
d = {'col'+str(i) : l[i] for i in range(len(l))}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

As your lists are arranged rather for rows than columns, I would first build the data frame as is and then transpose it:

```
data = [[0, 0, 0, 0,], [1, 1, 1, 1,]]
columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df = df.transpose()
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this is using [transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(yourList).T
```

If you want to change the columns names you can add

```
df = df.add_prefix('col')
```